How do I refresh a child component based on a function trigger from another child component?
I have a component questions-manager.component.html like this:
<div>
    <main>
        <div>
            <questions-component [title]="'title'" [id]="id" (changeStatus)="statusChange($event)"></questions-component>
            
            <div>
                <checklist-component [chId]="chId" (refreshChecklist)="refreshChecklist($event)"></checklist-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>

I want to refresh or re-render questions-component when I call refreshChecklist.
I gave this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-change-detection-strategy a try but this didn't work.
What can I do here to achieve this?

What exactly do you mean by "refresh" / "re-render"? Your questions-component should be composed in a way that it receives the necessary data from the parent component as inputs and dynamically reacts to input changes. However with the little context you have given, it's not really possible to tell you what might be wrong with your setup.

It should work out of the box in most cases. Could you show, what are you doing in refreshChecklist() in questions-manager.component.html and maybe some of the questions-component details?

Angular change detection should handle redrawing your components automatically.
I suggest this setup:
Store (or obtain via service call) the list of questions in questions-manager.
Then, pass this list as an input to your questions-component and checklist-component.
When the checklist-component changes, pass the new list through an output to the questions-manager.
This should trigger questions-component to re-render based on the new questions.

You could pass a context to questions-component as input and this component would subscribe to a subject in the context.
interface QuestionareContext {
     refresh$: Subject<any>;
}

Passing the input:
<questions-component [ctx]="context" ...>

Then anytime a refresh is needed in questions-component, just trigger the next value of the subject.
Subscribing the subject:
this.addSubscription(this.ctx.refresh$.subscribe(() => {
    ...
}));

In your component base class:
protected addSubscription(subscription: Subscription) {
    this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    for (let sub of this.subscriptions) {
        sub.unsubscribe();
    }
    this.subscriptions = [];
}


I advice using self-unsubscribing observables using takeUntil(this.destroy$), rather than keeping list of subscriptions. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe
